# CSS and HTML centred nav bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to get my nav bar centered properly and with a 1px border on the left and right of each nav item (as opposed to 2px where two borders join together).

The site is www.berryconcept.co.uk/vouchfor

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: Do you mean having the links centered?

Comment: I mean to have the whole ul centred.

Answer (score 2):

To not have double border in the junction, you can give the items no border left and give the `:first-child` item border left: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: And if you want to support even older browsers, you can set overflow: hidden; on the parent (ul) and margin-left: -1px; on the children (to obscure the first border-left, for example).

Comment: @reisio Even older than CSS2's `:first-child`? It is supported by all modern browsers and the last 3 major versions of IE: 7/8/9. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17 Surely that must be enough, how do you justify adding garbage CSS?

Comment: @ANeves: like this: "And if you want to support even older browsers,"

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I generally proceed as follows:

I add the border for the first link as a `border-left: 1px solid #ccc;` on either the `<ul>` or the `<div>` encasing the ul and then set it so each `<li>` element has `border-right: 1px solid #ccc;` set.

Hopefully this helps.

If you post your code on a jsfiddle I'll update it for you. :)

Comment: Any advice on the centering issue? :)

Comment: Centering the <ul>? Or the <li>'s inside?

Applying `margin: 0 auto;` will align it in the center.

However if you're trying to make the <li> elements center you'll be applying padding left & right to the UL (and reducing its width accordingly) so that the LI elements move into the middle fo the menu bar. 

Hopefully this explained it? :D

Comment: Well, yes, but I have tried this. If I reduce the width of ul and then add padding, it works on some browsers, but then on others it wraps onto a second line.

Comment: Upload everything to a jsfiddle for me quick so I can have a look? :) http://jsfiddle.net